# Check for null after malloc in Little kernel bootloader?

Tags: linux-kernel, malloc, bootloader

In Little Kernel boot loader at many places no check for null after malloc or memalign.

For example : in

```
void flash_init(void) at flash_cmdlist = memalign(32, 1024);

char *target_cmdline(char *org_cmdline)
{
    cmdline = (char *)malloc(MAX_CMDLINE_LEN);
    memset(cmdline, 0, MAX_CMDLINE_LEN);
}
```

Is it assumed that malloc will not return null while booting?

Comment: Maybe they didn't check for errors because if the bootloader fails to malloc the device is bricked anyway ;)

Comment: So it should be checked for null?

Comment: You should always check for null, however how does the bootloader recover if it can't malloc? There is nowhere to recover to... It could reboot, but this can lead to non stop rebooting. Maybe that's why they didn't check for null.

Comment: I do wonder however why you want to malloc in a bootloader... but that's offtopic ;p

Comment: @DipSwitch We require memory for initialization the basic setup.Little kernel.

Comment: And this can't be done by some variables placed in the .data .stack or .bss section? Malloc can indeed fail, for something crucial like a bootloader you want rock solid software which would always work unless there are hardware failures.

Answer (score 1):

shunty, you should probably do some code background research :)

The code you're referring to isn't actually contributed by the author of LK but from Google/Qcom, and that part (aboot) was created using some dump of the legacy android bootloader, I still have files which look way too similar but cannot publish them to public domain.

The reason they don't check for null is because in the legacy bootloader heap was implemented as VERY basic, there was no free, no chunks, just allocate, increment address and forget about it because heap wouldn't be used for very long anyway so that wasn't a problem there but in LK which in itself is very much capable of OS like tasks, it is just plain wrong since heap supports free and other standard heap functions.

Comment: I code i am looking is downloaded form code aurora LK project.And in platform there is no check against null while allocating memory.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I'm trying to say, the code isn't from the author of LK, but from codeaurora Qualcomm, they have crappy code there, check the timer for qsd8k, it can cause thread deadlock and potentially even crash the whole system because timer is reset, so if a thread is preempted in mdelay and another thread uses the timer, BOOM.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for null, however how does the bootloader recover if it can't malloc? There is nowhere to recover to... It could reboot, but this can lead to non stop rebooting. Maybe that's why they didn't check for null.